# Issue displaying GeoTIFF raster data as layer in Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, raster, geotiff

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to display GeoTIFF raster data as a layer on a Leaflet map. Here's the problem I'm encountering:

I have an HTML page with JavaScript code that fetches a GeoTIFF file and attempts to display it on a Leaflet map. However, when trying to read the image data from the GeoTIFF file, I encountered the following error in the browser console: "TypeError: image.getWidth is not a function".

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GeoTIFF Viewer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        #map-container {
            height: 500px;
        }
        #navigation-controls {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        button {
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-container"></div>
    <div id="navigation-controls">
        <button id="zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
        <button id="zoom-out">Zoom Out</button>
        <button id="move-left">Move Left</button>
        <button id="move-right">Move Right</button>
        <button id="move-up">Move Up</button>
        <button id="move-down">Move Down</button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geotiff"></script>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map-container').setView([0, 0], 2);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        // Step 1: Load GeoTIFF file
        var url = 'd.tif'; // Replace with your GeoTIFF file URL

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
            .then(arrayBuffer => {
                return GeoTIFF.fromArrayBuffer(arrayBuffer);
            })
            .then(tiff => {
                var image = tiff.getImage();
                var width = image.getWidth();
                var height = image.getHeight();
                
                // Read pixel values
                return image.readRasters({ window: [0, 0, width, height] });
            })
            .then(rasters => {
                var imageData = rasters[0]; // Assuming a single band image
                var bounds = [[0, 0], [imageData.length, imageData[0].length]]; // Update bounds as needed
                
                var imageOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageData, bounds);
                imageOverlay.addTo(map);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading GeoTIFF:', error);
            });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error description from console:

```html
index2.php:63 Error loading GeoTIFF: TypeError: image.getWidth is not a function
    at index2.php:49:23
```

Could someone please provide guidance on how to properly read and display GeoTIFF raster data as a layer on a Leaflet map? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!